# Memory scanner with a slow scan

Tags: c++, c, delphi, memory

I'm working on a Memory Scanner, but the scan is so slow.. can anybody help-me improve it?

```
procedure FirstScan(scantype, scanvalue: string);
var
 value :integer;
 dwEndAddr : dword;
 i:dword;
 mbi : TMemoryBasicInformation;
begin
  while (VirtualQuery(Pointer(DWORD(mbi.BaseAddress) + MBI.RegionSize), MBI, SizeOf(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION))=SizeOf(TMemoryBasicInformation)) do begin
   if (MBI.State = MEM_COMMIT) and (MBI.Protect = PAGE_READWRITE) then begin
    dwEndAddr := DWORD(mbi.BaseAddress) + MBI.RegionSize;
     for i := DWORD(MBI.BaseAddress) to (dwEndAddr - 1 - sizeof(DWORD)) do begin
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      try
       if scantype = '1 Byte' then begin
        value := PBYTE(i)^;
        if scanvalue = IntToStr(value) then ListBox1.Items.Add(IntToHex(i,8));
       end;
       //others scantypes here...
      except
       Break;
      end;
     end;
   end; 
  end;
end;
```

I've learned that I need to read 4096 byte pages at a time then store those in memory and do operations on it, until I need a new page then get another 4096 byte page...

But I don't know how can I do that...

Can anybody help-me? The code can be in C or C++...

Comment: If your question is really just "Why is this specific code slow?" then you should take it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead because your question is too localized to be of general interest here on Stack Overflow. But if your question is just generally "How do I make arbitrary slow code faster?" then you should ask that directly instead.

Comment: mbi.BaseAddress and MBI.RegionSize are undefined on entry to VirtualQuery() - uninitialized stack data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make slow code fast, there are a few things you can do. First, make sure your code is *correct*. Wrong results are still wrong results, even if you get them quickly. To that end, make sure that when you call `VirtualQuery`, you're passing in valid values for all the parameters. At that start of this function `mbi` is uninitialized, so the result of `DWORD(mbi.BaseAddress) + MBI.RegionSize` will be who-knows-what.

Once you have correctly working code, there are two ways to make it faster:

1. Find the slow parts and make them fast. To do this right, you need a profiler. A profiler will observe your program as it runs, and then tell you what percentage of time your program spent executing each part. That tells you where to focus your efforts.
2. Replace slow algorithms with faster algorithms. This might mean throwing away the entire function, or it might mean fixing just certain parts of the code.

For example, profiling might show that you spend a lot of time call `ProcessMessages`. You can't really make that function any faster since it's part of the VCL, but you *can* call it less often. You might even find that you don't need to call it at all, if the thread you're running this code on isn't expected to receive any messages that need processing.

Profiling might show that you're spending a lot of time doing string comparisons. If the *starts* of your strings are frequently equal, and usually only differ at the end, then you might wish to change your string-comparison algorithm to start comparing strings at the last character instead of the first.

Profiling might show that you're spending a lot of time converting integers into strings before you compare them. Most programming languages support comparing integers directly, so instead of using a string-comparing algorithm, you could try using an integer-comparing algorithm instead. You could convert `scanvalue` to an integer with `StrToInt(scanvalue)` and compare it directly to `value`.

Profiling might show that you're repeatedly calculating the same result from the same input. If a value doesn't change over some portion of a program, then values calculated from it won't change, either. You can reduce the cost of converting values by doing it only when a value has changed. For example, if you do integer comparisons, then you'll probably find that the integer version of `scanvalue` doesn't change in your function. You could convert `scanvalue` to an integer once at the start of the function, and then compare `value` to that inside the loop instead of calling `StrToInt(scanvalue)` lots of times.

Comment: Thanks, I will fix these mistakes and back here to post the results.

Comment: Of course I can see the change. But I've voted you down because you changed the entire question, completely invalidating the answers you'd gotten to the original question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017411/memory-scanner-always-returning-the-same-results

Answer (score 10):

I can help you a bit...get that `Application.ProcessMessages` out of the inner loop.  You're calling it for every.  single.  byte.  you.  scan.  You don't need to be quite *that* responsive to window messages.  :)

Move it up into the outer loop, and you should see a significant speed increase.  I'd say spawn a thread and get rid of `Application.ProcessMessages` altogether, as it's really not this code's job to handle, but i'm not sure how/whether Delphi does threads.

Also....you're passing the scan params as strings?  If you insist on doing that, set an int or enum or something before you start the loop that says what scan type to use, convert the value to a useful type for your search, and compare that.    String comparisons tend to be slower than integer comparisons, particularly when you're creating new strings each time.

Comment: It's all a pile of Complete Removal of Application.Processmessages.  Threading this off should be fairly easy in Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

Also: you're converting the current pointer to a string *for every byte* you access. Yech, horribly slow. Instead, change scanvalue to a BYTE at the start of your procedure and do the comparison directly on BYTEs.

Finally -- pull the "if scantype = '1 byte'" out of the for i:=DWORD(MBI.BaseAddress) loop. You don't want to be doing that "if" statement for every byte -- instead, do

```
if scantype = '1 byte' then
  for i:= DWORD(...)
else if scantype='other scan type' then...
```

and so on. (And yes, you should convert that "if scantype" comparison to an enum or whatnot.)