# Memory scanner always returning the same results

Tags: delphi, memory

With this code I guess the scan was faster, but the scan always return the SAME address.

E.G.:

```
00123456
00124567
00135478
00145893
00123456 //start repeat 
00124567
00135478
00145893
00123456 //start repeat 
00124567
00135478
00145893
```

This is my procedure:

```
procedure SCANBYTE(value: integer);
var
 lpflOldProtect: dword;
 s: size_t;
 mbi: MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION;
 SI: SYSTEM_INFO;
 lpStartAddress, lpStopAddress: dword;
 addr: dword;
 i: dword;
begin
 GetSystemInfo(si);
 lpStartAddress := dword(SI.lpMinimumApplicationAddress);
 lpStopAddress := dword(SI.lpMaximumApplicationAddress);
 for addr := lpStartAddress to lpStopAddress do begin
  S:= VirtualQuery(Pointer(addr), MBI, SizeOf(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION));
  if (S=SizeOf(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)) and (MBI.State = MEM_COMMIT) and (MBI.Type_9 = MEM_PRIVATE) and (MBI.RegionSize>0) and (MBI.Protect = PAGE_READWRITE) then begin
   for i := dword(MBI.BaseAddress) to (dword(MBI.BaseAddress) + dword(MBI.RegionSize)) - 4096 do begin
     if value = PBYTE(i)^ then ListBox1.Items.Add(IntToHex(i,8));
   end;
  end;
 end;
end;
```

I guess the problem is at the last FOR loop:

```
(...)
for i := dword(MBI.BaseAddress) to (dword(MBI.BaseAddress) + dword(MBI.RegionSize)) - 4096 do begin
(...)
```

But I really don't know..
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You run your code in a loop from the start address to the end address. The address `addr` increases by **1** each time around the loop. `VirtualQuery` gives you information about entire pages. All the addresses in a page have the same base address. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366902.aspx) tells you, "This value is rounded down to the next page boundary."

Look more closely, and you should see that `mbi.BaseAddress` remains the same for 4096 iterations of your outer loop (assuming 4096 is the page size). Thus, you're re-scanning the same block of memory over and over again. (That might also explain [why your code is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10015598/33732).)